# Searchable properties on site

Tags: search

Lets say I got some buildings. For each building I want to add some documents, pictures and a task list. So I create one site per building using a "building site template"

Then I got some properties on each building, like adress, floors, etc. And I want to search using boolean operators like "Location:'MyCity'"

How can this be solved? Can I add searchable properties on a site? Or do I need a list where the listitems somehow match the sites?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add searchable properties to a site (SPWeb). Maintain a list of links to each site with searchable properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about new Websites for each Building? or Site Collections? At all you can achieve what you want with the search and managed properties. You just have to add your crawled properties to the managed properties and then you either can define own search scopes or you can use it out of box. Questions about Websites or Site Collections was because thescope. If new Websites inside a Site Collection you can use the "This site scope":

HTH, cheers Stefan

Comment: I was thinking of one website for each building. I will have a look at it. Thanks!